# What is the meaning of render.domElement, what this argument meant for?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am learning to manipulate three_js code in a profound way. I faced with one last line, want to be aware of what that last line is meant for. Could not find any reference on MDN.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(); // scene initialization
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 ); // see syntax one line below
// syntax: .PerspectiveCamera(FOV, aspectRatio, nearClippingPlane, farClippingPlane);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); // WebGLRenderer initialization 
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ); // render aspectRatio

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Appends renderer as a node to document.BODY probably to `<canvas>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`renderer.domElement` refers to the `<canvas>` element where the scene will be rendered.
It is either generated automatically by the renderer, or is the canvas that you pass to the renderer via parameters object that the `THREE.WebGLRenderer` function accepts.
See: [Line 61](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r106/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L61) and [Line 78](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r106/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L78) of [WebGLRenderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r106/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js).

So the last line just appends this `<canvas>` as a child of the `body` in your html page. That's it really.